# Google Codelab - Image Classification Transfer Learning - gcloud beta ml init-project error

Tags: google-cloud-ml

I'm starting the Google Codelab on transfer learning with GCP:  After installing the cloud sdk in the Cloud shell:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pillow
curl https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-ml/scripts/setup_cloud_shell.sh | bash
export PATH=${HOME}/.local/bin:${PATH}
```

I cannot go beyond the following command:
`gcloud beta ml init-project`

which returns the following:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ml) Invalid choice: 'init-project'.
Usage: gcloud beta ml [optional flags] <group>
  group may be           language | speech | video | vision
For detailed information on this command and its flags, run:
  gcloud beta ml --help
```

Ref: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb102-txf-learning/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#2

I guess the codelab is old and the SDK has been changed.  Can anybody point me to documentation that is perhaps more up-to-date for using the cloud sdk to do transfer learning?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more up to date codelabs that steps you through transfer learning:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/scd-coastline/index.html

That init-project call is no longer required; it happens automatically.